# How use character '$' in a Invoke-SSHCommand without error

Tags: powershell, winforms, posh-ssh

I try to get information from a Linux server in a powershell script

I use the Windows forms and i get the informations in a RichTextBox.

There is no problem for some basic commands.

Example :

```
$infoversion = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "uname -r"

$Result_Info.text += "Kernel Version : $($infoversion.Output) + ("`n")
```

But when i use a command with a pipe and the '$' character, it doesn't work.

Example :

```
$infouptime = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "uptime -p | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'"

$Result_Info.text += "Server up since $($infouptime.Output)" + ("`n")
```

(This command work directly on the server)

I try to set `\$` or `'e` or `'$'` or `"+chr(38)+"` but nothing works

If someone can help me, it will be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell uses the backtick `` ` `` as the escape character in expandable strings:

```
$infouptime = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "uptime -p | awk '{print `$2,`$3,`$4,`$5,`$6,`$7}'"
```

Alternatively, since you don't actually have any variables that need expanding, you could use a single-quoted string literal - the escape sequence for a literal `'` is simply `''`:

```
$infouptime = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command 'uptime -p | awk ''{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'''
```

Comment: This $infouptime = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command 'uptime -p | awk ''{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}''' work fine.
I'm very happy and i realy thank u :)